# usage of norm(al) and put in vim

Tags: vim, vi

I am beginner using Vim Editor for addressing the code review comments.
Kindly elaborate "put" and "norm" in vim search.

Comment: Using a search engine might help you better understand [these](http://briancarper.net/blog/165/) [type](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html) of commands.

Answer (score 2):

Vim comes with an extensive documentation that you can access with the `:help` command.

Use `:help :command` to get help on a specific command.